# User Interface for crud operation in Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I want to create web interface for CRUD operation using JSF as frontend and hive as backend.
Can anybody please guide me what all things/step I need in Hive to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: poorly framed question with no base..

Answer (score 0):

Hive [comes with a JDBC driver](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-JDBC). In the dowloadable archive, it is available in the lib directory (hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar for the current version). [Here](https://hive.apache.org/index.html) you should start.